# pynput and GlobalHotKeys not receiving any keyboard events

Tags: python, linux, windows, portability, pynput

This code works on Windows 10 but not on Linux. Linux does not seem to receive any keyboard events at all. When interrupting the program on Linux with Ctrl-C, this is the stack trace:

```
  File "/home/andreas/src/magnetfeld-aux/keyboard_events.py", line 22, in <module>
    key = kbd_q.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/queue.py", line 171, in get
    self.not_empty.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 312, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Here is the code:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from queue import Queue

kbd_q = Queue(maxsize=1)

def on_activate_s(): 
    kbd_q.put("Hotkey s")


listener = keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
    's': on_activate_s,
})
listener.start()

while True:
    key = kbd_q.get()
    if key:
        print(key)
```

How do I get this to run on Linux?

Comment: Just tried your exact code with `pynput` version 1.7.5 inside of ipython (version 7.13.0) and python3.8. This works fine on my end (on a ubuntu 20.04 based distro). Problem is likely in pynput's end which probably does not yet fully work with 3.9. (or less likely but possible, maybe because of 3.9's threading/queue modules).

Comment: @NordineLotfi now I tested this with python3.7.12 and pynput 1.7.6, on a Debian system (with a pyenv for a dedicated python3.7), and I don't seem to get any keyboard events. I suspect something else is amiss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that was missing was `listener.wait()`, after starting the listener.
This works:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from queue import Queue

kbd_q = Queue(maxsize=1)

def on_activate_s(): 
    kbd_q.put("Hotkey s")


listener = keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
    's': on_activate_s,
})
listener.start()
listener.wait()

while True:
    key = kbd_q.get()
    if key:
        print(key)
```

Comment: This only works when running in PyCharm. When running in a Gnome terminal in Wayland, no keyboard events are detected anymore.